# sqlite3.OperationalError: near ":59": syntax error

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm trying to update my database. I want to change None to time and while I'm running it

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ":59": syntax error
```

my code to update is :

```
    now = datetime.now()
    trigger_time = str(now.strftime("%H:%M"))
    db.execute(f"""Update Signals set Triger_Time = {trigger_time} where ID = {int(signal_id)}""")
```

**SOLVED BY (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69661333/16613629)**

Answer :
You forget about quotes around Triger_Time:

```
now = datetime.now()
trigger_time = str(now.strftime("%H:%M"))
db.execute(f"""Update Signals set Triger_Time = '{trigger_time}' where ID = {int(signal_id)}""")
```

Comment: It's better to use parameter substitution rather than string formatting to insert values into SQL statements - see [How to use variables in SQL statements in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/902408/5320906).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget about quotes around Triger_Time:

```
now = datetime.now()
trigger_time = str(now.strftime("%H:%M"))
db.execute(f"""Update Signals set Triger_Time = '{trigger_time}' where ID = {int(signal_id)}""")
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the accepted answer of adding quotation marks will solve your immediate issue, it's generally preferred to use [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-can-prepared-statements-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks) rather than string formatting to build SQL code.

```
now = datetime.now()
trigger_time = str(now.strftime("%H:%M"))
db.execute("Update Signals set Triger_Time = ? where ID = ?", [trigger_time, int(signal_id)])
```